# JSX props should not use .bind() - how to avoid using bind?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have a container that I need to change the UI form showing the form or showing a success page.

The container has a state.showSuccess and I need the MyFormModule to be able to call the container to change the state.

The below code works but I'm getting the following warning:

> JSX props should not use `.bind()`

How can I get this to work without using .bind()?

```
...
const myPage = class extends React.Component {
  state = { showSuccess: false };
  showSuccess() {
   this.setState({
      showSuccess: true,
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { showSuccess } = this.state;
    if (showSuccess) {...}
    ....
    <MyFormModule showSuccess={this.showSuccess.bind(this)} />
```

Comment: Perhaps use an arrow function?: `showSuccess={() => this.showSuccess()}`

Comment: @CRice that did it thanks! please post an answer so I can vote it up for you.

Comment: If you don't want an arrow function in your JSX, you can also bind it in the constructor

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should first [understand **WHY** this is a bad practice](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md).

The main reason here, is that `.bind` is returning a new function reference.
This will happen on each `render` call, which may lead to a performance hit.

You got 2 options:

1. Use the constructor to `bind` your handlers (this will run only **once**).

   ```
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.showSuccess = this.showSuccess.bind(this);
   }
   ```
2. Or create your handlers with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) so they will use the
   lexical context for `this`, hence you won't need to `bind` them at
   all ([you will need a babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)):

   ```
   showSuccess = () => {
     this.setState({
       showSuccess: true,
     });
   }
   ```

You should **not** use this pattern (as others suggested):

```
showSuccess={() => this.showSuccess()}
```

Because this will as well create a new function on each render.
So you may bypass the warning but you are still writing your code in a bad practice design.

From the [ESLint docs](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md#no-bind-or-arrow-functions-in-jsx-props-reactjsx-no-bind):

> A bind call or arrow function in a JSX prop will create a brand new
>   function on every single render. This is bad for performance, as it
>   will result in the garbage collector being invoked way more than is
>   necessary. It may also cause unnecessary re-renders if a brand new
>   function is passed as a prop to a component that uses reference
>   equality check on the prop to determine if it should update.

Comment: You're right, it is a potential performance issue (as the docs admit), but in general, [it's probably okay](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#is-it-ok-to-use-arrow-functions-in-render-methods)

Comment: Yeah, if the OP has a linting rule that warns about "_JSX props should not use.bind()_" then we might want to explain why this warning exists and how to make the code better and not bypass the rule :)

Answer (score 2):

Use an arrow function when defining showSuccess

```
showSuccess = () => {
  this.setState({
    showSuccess: true,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an arrow function since they automatically inherit the `this` context of wherever they are defined.

```
showSuccess={() => this.showSuccess()}
```

Here is a link to the [facebook documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html) on this subject, which lists this method among others as a solution. Interestingly, they also list using `.bind` in the prop as one of the solutions, even though it produces a warning when actually used.

From that documentation, you'll note that this is a potential performance issue, since the function will be recreated on every render:

> Note:
>
> Using an arrow function in render creates a new function each time the
>   component renders, which may have performance implications (see
>   below).

But also from the same link:

> Is it OK to use arrow functions in render methods? Generally speaking,
>   yes, it is OK, and it is often the easiest way to pass parameters to
>   callback functions.
>
> If you do have performance issues, by all means, optimize!

So I would say if your component will be re-rendering very frequently, you should use one of the other solutions: bind in the constructor, or define the method with an arrow function in the first place. But if not, use whatever method seems cleanest to you.

Comment: this is the same bad practice. it will create a new function instance same as `.bind` does.

Comment: its an anonymous function, it will get created with every render

Comment: Yeah, if the OP has a linting rule that warns about "_JSX props should not use.bind()_" then we might want to explain why this warning exists and how to make the code better and not bypass the rule :)